# Automatically detect minification failures in ASP.NET MVC bundling

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, model-view-controller, deployment, bundling-and-minification

From time to time I notice the following error message on the top of my CSS bundle produced by ASP.NET MVC:

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(7933,26): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found ':'
(7933,26): run-time error CSS1042: Expected function, found ':'
(7933,26): run-time error CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found ':'
(7934,30): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found ':'
(7934,30): run-time error CSS1042: Expected function, found ':'
(7934,30): run-time error CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found ':'
 */
```

These errors always go silently through the build, deployment and unit tests and are very hard to notice. Is there any solution to automatically catch them? It is hard to get that from the unit test as there's no content folder being copied to the unit test project. Preferably this should fail the build or at least unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and wanted to unit test the minification, after some false starts trying to mock the `BundleContext`, I opted to just directly test the minification provided by webgrease `Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.Minifier`, slight issue was the `BundleItem` is internal to System.Web.Optimization so I had to do reflection:

```
  //arrange
  BundleCollection bundles = new BundleCollection();

  // my static bundler config in mvc
  BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(bundles); 

  // act and assert
  Assert.Multiple(() =>
  {
    foreach (var bundle in bundles)
    {
      // CAUTION: Reflection to private member!
      var items = typeof(Bundle).GetProperty("Items", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(bundle) as IEnumerable<Object>;
      foreach (Object item in items)
      {
        var minifier = new Minifier();
        var type = item.GetType();
        var path = type.GetProperty("VirtualPath")?.GetValue(item) as String;

        // todo: handle "BundleDirectoryItem" too ...
        if (type.Name == "BundleItem")
        {
          // todo: transform your virtual path to a physical path to the file at design time
          var file = File.ReadAllText(path);
          String min;
          if (path.EndsWith("css"))
          {
            min = minifier.MinifyStyleSheet(file);
          }
          else
          {
            min = minifier.MinifyJavaScript(file);
          }
          Assert.IsNotNull(min, $"Failed to get minified output for '{path}'");
          Assert.Zero(minifier.Errors.Count, $"Minification failed for '{path}', errors:\r\n{String.Join("\r\n", minifier.Errors)}");
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! JFYI: I had to manually link my content in unit tests csproj file: `<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\MyWebSite\Content\**\*.*">
      <Link>Content\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>`

Comment: Shouldn't Assert.Zero(minifier.Errors.Count) be checking for > 0?

Answer (score 1):

In a project that does not contain tests, using the [James Close answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55907634/2709005), I was able to display an alert with the minification failures when loading the system, although it did not cause the compilation to fail, we managed to catch the failures in the development environment:

```
public static IHtmlString Render(this BundleCollection bundles, string bundleVirtualPath) {
    Bundle bundle = bundles.GetBundleFor(bundleVirtualPath);
    List<IHtmlString> renderTags = new List<IHtmlString>();

    ... omitted for simplification

    List<string> errors;
    if (!bundle.IsValid(out errors)) {
        renderTags.Add(new HtmlString($"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors))}');</script>"));
    }

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, renderTags));
}


private static bool IsValid(this Bundle bundle, out List<string> errors) {
    errors = new List<string>();

    // Get items in included order
    BundleContext bundleContext = new BundleContext(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), new BundleCollection(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    IEnumerable<BundleFile> bundleFiles = bundle.EnumerateFiles(bundleContext);
    bool isStyleBundle = (bundle is StyleBundle);

    foreach (BundleFile bundleFile in bundleFiles) {
        string physicalPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(bundleFile.IncludedVirtualPath),
                fileContent = File.ReadAllText(physicalPath);

        // Create minifier used by webgrease System.Web.Optimization
        var minifier = new Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.Minifier();
        if (isStyleBundle) {
            minifier.MinifyStyleSheet(fileContent);
        } else {
            minifier.MinifyJavaScript(fileContent);
        }

        // Verify error in minification
        if (minifier.Errors.Any()) {
            errors.Add($"Minification failed for {bundleFile.IncludedVirtualPath}, errors:{Environment.NewLine}{string.Join(Environment.NewLine, minifier.Errors)}");
        }
    }

    return errors.Any();
}
```

I hope the above code can help someone in the future.

Comment: MVC/ASP noob question: where should the Render function be placed?

Comment: Agree with @mBardos, where are you putting this code Renato?

Comment: I call the Render method after the body tag when are scripts and after head tag when are styles